# should I create a separate table for password and usernames?

Tags: database, security, hashtable, md5, database-security

hello am wondering if it's better to store the usernames and passwords in a separate table if I used hashing? also is there any link to read more about databases security I have read about hashing and rainbow tables thanks

here is someone's opinion [image]

and here some opposite opinions

[image]

please help I got confused

Answer (score 0):

Finnbogi and Marc are **much** more on point than Richard.

Richard's only point on access controls may be applied to separate tables is not a real-world scenario and your time would be much better spent on actual security controls rather than his contrived hypothetical. Some resources on doing this securely:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

And review your database's security documentation (e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/security.html)

Comment: Thanks those links were really helpful but correct me if am wrong it doesn't actually matter if I save them in a separate table or the same table as I follow those security rules right ?!